# Passing list variable to Subprocess.call function

Tags: python

I am trying to pass the variable `line` inside a `for` loop that is calling a `subprocess.call` to calculate the unix command `cksum`.

```
with open('./my_filelist', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print "Printing Checksum --->"
        print ""
        subprocess.call(["cksum",line])
```

Should print the `cksum` of all the files in `./my_filelist`.

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines returned by the `file.readlines` method all end with a newline character (except the last line if the file does not end with a trailing newline). You should strip the line of the trailing newline character; otherwise the newline character would be treated as part of the file name when passed to `cksum` as an argument:

```
subprocess.call(["cksum", line.rstrip()])
```

Comment: How can I assign the subprocess.call to a variable? as this is only printing on std.out. tried assigning to a variable, but it just prints '0'.

Comment: `subprocess.call` returns the status code of the command being executed, and `0` means that the command executed successfully. If you need the output of the command, you should call `subprocess.check_output` instead.